# Regular expression to match a character only once before any whitespace

Tags: java, regex

In Java, what regular expression would I use to match a string that has exactly one colon and makes sure that the colon appears before any whitespace?

For example, it should match these strings:

```
label: print "Enter input"
But: I still had the money.
ghjkdhfjkgjhalergfyujhrageyjdfghbg:
area:54
```

But not

```
label: print "Enter input:"
There was one more thing: I still had the money.
ghfdsjhgakjsdhfkjdsagfjkhadsjkhflgadsjklfglsd
area::54
```

Comment: Why not the second one in the negative examples? And have you tried something yourself?

Comment: The colon in the second one appears after some whitespace. And I'm really fresh to regex, so I didn't want to struggle through it myself =P

Comment: @Kevin now why should we struggle through it for you? ;) You should read a [good tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Regex is good knowledge you will get to use often enough.

Comment: @m.buettner: Although I don't want to admit it, +1 for being right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use it with `matches` (which requires to match the entire string), you could use

```
[^\\s:]*:[^:]*
```

Which means: arbitrarily many non-`whitespace`, non-`:` characters, then a `:`, then more arbitrarily many non-`:` characters.

I've really only used two regex concepts: (negated) [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

If you want to require at least one character before or after `:`, replace the corresponding `*` with `+` (as jlordo pointed out in a comment).

Comment: +1, but he probably wants the `+` quantifier before the semicolon.

Comment: @jlordo hm, good point although it hasn't been specified anywhere. But I'll add it anyway

Comment: yeah, that's why I wrote probably ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
^[^\s:]*:(?!.*:)
```

If your strings can contain line breaks, use the DOTALL flag or change the regex to the following:

```
(?s)^[^\s:]*:(?!.*:)
```

Comment: Okay, now it will still match the last counter-example ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what we call white space, it could be

```
[^\\p{Space}:]*:[^:]
```

Comment: The `.+` will allow whitespace and you are allowing multiple `:`.

Comment: Not quite. You're missing a `*` at the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you started:

```
 Matcher MatchedPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+\\:{1}[\"\\w\\s\\.]*)$").matcher("yourstring");
```